# the use of parentheses in function .truncate()

Tags: python-2.7

What can the parentheses after the function .truncate() be used for? I tried putting different numbers in there to see if it would only truncate that amount of characters, but it always truncated the entire file.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv
opened_writable_file = open(filename, "w")
opened_writable_file.truncate(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The method `truncate()` truncates the file's size. Size is a parameter
>   send to the function. If the optional `size` argument is present, the
>   file is truncated to (at most) that size.
>
> The size defaults to the current position. The current file position
>   is not changed. Note that if a specified size exceeds the file's
>   current size, the result is platform-dependent.

Reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_truncate.htm

> With `truncate()`, you can declare how much of the file you want to
>   remove, based on where you're currently at in the file. Without
>   parameters, `truncate()` acts like `w`, whereas `w` always just wipes the
>   whole file clean. So, these two methods **can** act identically, but they
>   don't necessarily.

Reference: 
[Why truncate when we open a file in 'w' mode in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562100/why-truncate-when-we-open-a-file-in-w-mode-in-python)

> truncate() function does this: ...it only "empties the file" if the
>   current position is the start of the file—but since we just opened the
>   file (and not in a mode), the current position is the start, so that
>   isn't relevant. We're truncating to an empty file.

Reference:
[Behaviour of truncate() method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917197/behaviour-of-truncate-method-in-python)

Comment: I don't understand. I assumed that the parentheses where to declare how much of the file i wanted to truncate, but no matter what number i put there it truncated the entire file