# file.readable() overwriting external text files - bug or bad code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Am taking a tutorial on youtube for python3 - in this exercise the code runs just fine if I have the open "r" option selected for reading files. If I switch the "r" to a "w" it runs through fine the first time, tells me that it cannot read the file - which is the expected outcome. But when I look at employees.txt again or if I try to rerun the code with the "r" option enabled, I see that the text file is empty.

I have tried the syntax in every way I can think of, but so far, I have had no luck in figuring out why it empties the text file

How would you go about troubleshooting something like this? Or is there something obvious in my code that you see? (code is exactly like the course example).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Script Name - reading-files.fcc.py

employee_file = open("employees.txt", "r")

if employee_file.readable() == True:
    print(employee_file.read())
    employee_file.close()
    exit
else:
    print("Cannot read file.")
    employee_file.close()
    exit
```

Here is employee.txt:

```
Jim - Sales
Dwight - Sales
Pam - Sales
Michael - Manager
Oscar - Accounting
```

Comment: Opening in `w` mode truncates

Comment: thank you, @Primusa, I am still trying to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562100/why-truncate-when-we-open-a-file-in-w-mode-in-python) might be a good post for your consideration.

Opening the file in `w` mode will overwrite the file, meaning that unless you are writing anything to the file thereafter, it will effectively empty the file's contents- in your case with no additional text, rendering the file's contents blank.

Comment: that did help, thank you. I am wondering if opening the file in append mode is a good work around?

Comment: It depends what you are looking to accomplish- are you trying to add data to  `employees.txt` or simply read from it?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file with 'w' option, `employee_file.readable()` returns `False`, so it print a line, **close and save an empty file**.

Comment: Thank you, @SGKoish - I don't yet understand your hint but I will investigate based on your clue.